# Redirecting output not working after upgrading to IronPython 3

Tags: c#, ironpython

I've upgraded from IronPython 2 to IronPython 3, but after upgrading I am no longer able to get output.

My class:

```
public class UnityLogWriter : StreamWriter
{
    private readonly Action<string> logger;
    private string buffer = "";

    public UnityLogWriter(Action<string> logger, Stream s) : base(s)
    {
        if (logger == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        }
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        base.Write(value);
        buffer += value;

        var lines = buffer.Split('\n');
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (i == lines.Length - 1)
            {
                buffer = lines[i];
            }
            else
            {
                logger(lines[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code that redirects output:

```
var infoStream = new MemoryStream();
var infoWriter = new UnityLogWriter(Debug.Log, infoStream);
engine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(infoStream, infoWriter);
```

Using IronPython 2, this code works, but using IronPython 3 doesn't give any output.

I found [this documentation](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/blob/master/Documentation/upgrading-from-ipy2.md) about changes on IronPython 3 which included a section about redirecting output, but I am unsure how to implement this information.

Answer (score 0):

In IronPython 3, the way to redirect output has changed.

Instead of using `engine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput()`, you can use the `Console.SetOut()` method to redirect the output stream to your custom `TextWriter`.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something but would I first need to redirect ironpython to the console with `engine.Runtime.IO.RedirectToConsole();` then use `Console.SetOut(textWriter)` to send it to my textWriter? In my test I can see other console info being logged by my text writer but no python.

Comment: @RileyB, var infoWriter = new UnityLogWriter(Debug.Log); Console.SetOut(infoWriter);